# how do I split the single column of tabular form by two headers is sql oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, report, multiple-columns, where-clause, apex

I have an amount column in database for oracle apex which have multiple values some are < 0 and others are > 0. I want there to display in report on two columns Debit and Credit. How do I use SQL queries? Please help me in where clause.

```
select ANOID,
       PERNOID,
       PERNO,
       AMOUNT as "Credit" , -- < 0 
       AMOUNT as "Debit",   -- > 0
       DESC_,
       DEBIT,
       ROW_ID
  from DSVOUD
  where
  VOUID = :P11_VOUID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a CASE statement for those two columns:

```
select ANOID,
       PERNOID,
       PERNO,
       case when AMOUNT < 0 then AMOUNT end as "Credit" , 
       case when AMOUNT > 0 then AMOUNT end as "Debit",  
       DESC_,
       DEBIT,
       ROW_ID
  from DSVOUD
  where
  VOUID = :P11_VOUID
```

This will show null in the Debit column for Credit amounts and vice versa. You might want to add an `else 0` clause instead.